# Get the previous upgradecode that was used to install the application

Tags: c#

C# 2005 SP3

Is it possible to retrieve the pervious upgradeCode that was used to install the same application?

I have given our application to many or our clients.

They install our application using the MSI.

Everytime I release a new version for bug fixes or minor upgrades. In the setup project properties I increment the version number and change the product code (I always leave the same upgrade code). And I set the 'RemovePreviousVersion' to true.

However, a few weeks ago, I accidently changed the upgradeCode and released a new version to our customers. It was only now that a customer wanted to know why they have other instances of the same application in their 'add remove programs'. It installs ok, but they have to uninstall the previous version.

I am wondering is it possible to get back the original upgrade that was used to install those versions. As I used the same setup project, I no longer have that upgrade code?

I still have all my original setups.exe that were built with the original upgradecode, but I am not sure if they can help me.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you're trying to retrieve the UpgradeCode GUID for a product, so that you can embed it in the next version of your MSI i.e. you can't remember what it is.

If that is your question...

It's stored in the registry, so a bit of trawling on should pay dividends.

If you go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer
```

you'll find a whole lot of entries under UserData...\Products.  One or more of these will be your product.  If you then search in UpgradeCodes for keys containing the product key you'll find the GUIDS.

The only tricky bit is that they are written in a bizarre notation, so that:

{abcdefgh-ijkl-mnop-qrst-uvwxyz123456}

becomes:

hgfedcbalkjiponmrqtsvuxwzy214365

Comment: I was banging my head against the desk until I noticed similarities in the translated upgrade code to the one I was using. Jeez.